# When user tap push notification, what is the best way to close current viewcontroller and open new viewcontroller

Tags: ios

When user tap push notification, what is the best way to close current `UIViewController` and open new `UIViewController`?

for example,

A(Base `UIViewController`) open B(`UIViewController`) and open C(`UIViewController`)

and use tap home button, so app will enter background,

after then when a user receive a push notification, and tap it,

app will enter foreground.

I want to close B, C `UIViewController`(C controller may be opened or not), and open D(`UIViewController`)

like this A->D

Would you give me some tips?

Comment: You definitely should change word "tab" to "tap" because action is tapping.

Comment: Actually I'm a little bit lazy now to write full answer for that question. Your problem depends on app hierarchy. First of all take a look at AppDelegate's window object (UIWindow). Window object has a property called rootViewController (in your case it could be A, but not necessary). From that point you should dismiss or/and pop all view controllers and then add new view controller (D). It could be done by several ways (notification, looping and etc). Google for example "how to dismiss all view controllers", "how to pop to rootViewController" and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you will come from push, that means you will be coming from `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Write below line of code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];

[navigationArray removeAllObjects];    // This is just for remove all view controller from navigation stack.
// [navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 2];  // You can pass your index here
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
[navigationArray release];
```

I hope this is clear.

Note: As you are accessing navigation controller in app delegate, use below to access navigation controller.

```
(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I've followed was, in AppDelegate.m file you can implement the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Inside that you can have mechanism to identify the type of notification and according to that you can post your own notification using NSNotificationCenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openMyView" object:nil userInfo:myInfoDic];
```

Then inside notification observer method, you can perform a segue to your UIViewController that needs to display

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMySegue" sender:myDataDic];
```

You have to create the segue with the mentioned name in storyboard too. Hope you are familiar that process already.